# How can I post a comment to a wordpress blog?

Tags: python, wordpress, api

I have a django site that's tightly coupled with a wordpress blog.  I want to have a form on the django site that posts comments (for moderation) to the wordpress blog.

I keep seeing references to comment apis and xmlrpc, so I feel like this should be possible.

1) what POST / GET can I call, from python, to post a comment to a wordpress blogpost?

2) for extra points, do you know a python library that manages this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that [python-blogger](http://code.google.com/p/python-blogger/) project has friendly python wrapper over wordpress apis that you are looking for, there specifically is bug-report and a [patch](http://code.google.com/p/python-blogger/issues/detail?id=2) to have you post comment on the wordpress site using the [wordpress XMLRPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp) call.

Comment: Thanks - that patched library was great.  I had to wrestle with some XMLRPC wordpress issues, but with that resolved I think things are looking solid.