# using python [xmlrpc frontend] modules on google app engine to connect to a wordpress blog

Tags: python, wordpress, api, google-app-engine, xml-rpc

I'm using pyblog module (python blogger) [See P.S. at the bottom for wordpress_xmlrpc] to automate operations on a wordpress blog, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917905/how-can-i-post-a-comment-to-a-wordpress-blog). 
Pyblog home [page](http://code.google.com/p/python-blogger/) describes a simple using script:

```
import pyblog
blog = pyblog.WordPress('http://www.example.com/blog/xmlrpc.api', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
print blog.get_recent_posts()
```

When I run it locally, the script works fine. But when I deploy it on google app engine, I encounter the following error about the `blog.get_recent_posts` line:

```
return self.execute('metaWeblog.getRecentPosts', blogid, self.username, self.password, numposts)
File "/base/data/home/apps/myappname/1.371326087278559778/pyblog.py", line 93, in execute
raise BlogError(fault.faultString)
BlogError: parse error. not well formed
```

which refers to the following lines in `pyblog.py`:

```
try:
    r = getattr(self.server, methodname)(args)
except xmlrpclib.Fault, fault:
    raise BlogError(fault.faultString)
```

Removing the `try/except` the error occurred is indicated as:

```
Fault -32700: 'parse error. not well formed'
```

How to solve?

**P.S.: I've tried a similar script using [python-wordpress-xmlrpc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-wordpress-xmlrpc) library.** Running the example script suggested [here](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#quick-start)

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import GetUserInfo

wp = Client('http://mysite.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'password')
wp.call(GetUserInfo())
<WordPressUser: max>
```

raises the same error!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog/issues/89), it seems like a bug in wordpress. Can you print what you receive from wordpress? If it's the same issue you should see malformed html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that GAE blocks any outbound requests that do not use their URLFetch service at the foundation; you can't use ordinary sockets, for example.  Google's versions of urllib etc. have been modified so that they use URLFetch internally.

[Here's](http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2008/08/25/making-xmlrpc-calls-from-a-google-app-engine-application/) an old but very thorough article that discusses a similar XMLRPC situation and provides some solutions.